# Booting Linux on Mac with internal GPU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, intel-graphics, amd-graphics, graphic-card

I own a early 2011 MacBook Pro 15" (macOS Sierra). Some weeks ago, my discrete GPU (AMD Radeon) kinda broke (as soon as the Mac had to calculate something, the screen got distorted). Because of that, I downloaded gfxCardStatus, which let me manually switch to the internal grpahics card (wich works well now).

Now, i want to install Ubuntu Elementary (dual boot) which is not possible with the acutal GPU. Is there any possibility to change the default graphics card in the EFI/BIOS to always boot with the Intel HD chip?

Comment: There was a product recall for this sort of issue recently; I got a brand new screen for free for my similarly aged 17" MacBook Pro as a result. Worth checking (log in to the service part of the apple support website) if this is still available and if yours is covered!

Comment: I'm guessing this is your issue, although Apple apparently is not covering your model anymore: https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/